# Regex: replacing a string with prefix capture except for a given prefix

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want to replace a string, keeping the prefix, except when it contains a specific prefix.

For instance, any string like `"(*)-bar"` must be replaced with `"(*)-blah"` except when `"(*)"` matches `"baz"`:

```
foo-bar => should return foo-blah 
baz-bar => should remain baz-bar
```

The best I have so far trims the last letter of the prefix when replacing:

```
echo "foo-bar" | sed s/"[^(baz)]-bar"/$1-blah/
```

Comment: `[^(baz)]` doesn't mean what you think it does. `[^...]` matches a single character that isn't one of the characters in the brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *negative lookbehind*:

```
s/(?<!baz)-bar/-blah/
```

Most `sed` implementations don't have this advanced regexp feature, but it should work in more modern languages, such as perl.

Answer (score 1):

With sed :

```
$ echo "foo-bar" | sed '/^foo-baz/!s/^foo-.*$/foo-blah/'
foo-blah
$ echo "foo-baz" | sed '/^foo-baz/!s/^foo-.*$/foo-blah/'
foo-baz
```

If I decompose :

```
echo "foo-baz" | sed '/^foo-baz/!s/^foo-.*$/foo-blah/'
                      |        |||                   |
                      +  regex +|+ substitution part +
                                |
                              negation of regex
```